# Same IP address for `docker build` and `docker run`

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

In my Dockerfile I'm running an installer. This installer is configuring itself to use the current IP address.

Then, wenn `docker build` finishes, and when I then run the container, I need to use exactly the same IP address that was used during build.

How can I do this?

Comment: Usually you don't: the container IP address is an internal implementation detail that you can't usually directly access, and Docker will assign one somewhat arbitrarily based on host configuration and what other containers and networks are already running.  What part of the application requires such a specific IP address; can you include any relevant source code?

Comment: It's the Oracle Database 18c XE installer for Windows. I don't have any influence on what it does.